# Particular web-page not scrolling vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to scroll down [this](http://www.quizzinginc.com/user/index) page, it jumps to top? Already tried by changing the `overflow: hidden;` to Scroll or auto but problem is still there.

This problem persist in every browser. Please, provide an effective solution to this.

This is not a browser problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with javascript. Not entirely sure WHAT the problem is, but it's in the javascript. Go through the javascript, and see if you have anything that reacts to `scroll`.

Comment: I agree with junkfoodjunkie that it's the javascript. You should post your JS code here if you want more assistance.